# What is this way of a JavaScript function declaration called? (var) => {}

Tags: javascript, node.js

upon reading the latest NodeJS docs I encountered a new way of declaring a function:

```
fs.unlink('/tmp/hello', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
});
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system

Now I want to know how this `(var) => { <functon-content> }` type declaration is called, so that I can research more on it.

I have not yet found anything online regarding this topic. :(

Comment: ECMA6 function declaration : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. Please research around before posting such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature of the ECMAScript 6 called Arrow Function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.